# Unexpected return value on MariaDB stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Here is the sequence table:

| app | app_dt | seq_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2021-05-11 | 2 |

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GEN_APPL_NO`(
    in appType varchar(3),
    out applNo varchar(20)
)
begin
    declare prefix varchar(1) default 'E';
    declare seqNo int;
    declare seqLen int default 3;
    declare formNo varchar(20);
    
    select seq_id into  @seqNo  from seq_table
        where app = @appType and app_dt = curdate();

    if( @seqNo is null  )
    then
        set @seqNo = 1;
        insert into seq_table values ( @app , curdate(), @seqNo );
    else 
        update seq_table set seq_id= @seqNo +1 where app= @app and app_dt= curdate();
    end if;
    
    select @prefix || @appType || date_format(curdate(),'%Y%m%d') || lpad(@seqNo,@seqLen,0) into  applNo ;

end
```

The expected result would be `EABC20210511002`, but after call

```
CALL GEN_EFORM_NO('ABC',?)
```

it returns `null` without an error.

Comment: seq_id = curdate() in your select.  is this right?

Comment: You have a typo: `@applType` instead of `@appType` in the `select`

Comment: @Nick still not working after changing applType to  appType

Comment: @praveen should be app_dt = curdate(), it return null and nth is update / insert in the table 'seq'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your variables should have an @ in front of them; that will make them try to access a variable in the global scope instead of the parameters and locally declared variables in the procedure. This applies through your entire procedure, which should look like:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GEN_APPL_NO`(
    in appType varchar(3),
    out applNo varchar(20)
)
begin
    declare prefix varchar(1) default 'E';
    declare seqNo int;
    declare seqLen int default 3;
    declare formNo varchar(20);
    
    select seq_id into  seqNo  from seq_table
        where app = appType and app_dt = curdate();

    if( seqNo is null  )
    then
        set seqNo = 1;
        insert into seq_table values ( app , curdate(), seqNo );
    else 
        update seq_table set seq_id= seqNo +1 where app= app and app_dt= curdate();
    end if;
    
    select prefix || appType || date_format(curdate(),'%Y%m%d') || lpad(seqNo,seqLen,0) into  applNo ;

end
```

Note that in your `insert` and `update` statements you are trying to access `app`, which is not defined anywhere; do you perhaps mean `appType`?

Note I'm also assuming you have SQL mode [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`] enabled, otherwise you will need to use [`CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/concat/):

```sql
select concat(prefix, appType, date_format(curdate(),'%Y%m%d'), lpad(seqNo,seqLen,0)) into  applNo;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the insert/update statement should be appType, the insert/update statement works now,

I removed all '@' and change  select concat( prefix  , appType ,date_format(curdate(),'%Y%m%d') , lpad( seqNo , seqLen , '0' )) into  applNo;

but it still return null

Comment: @user3259913 I have made a demo with just the select operating with dummy values here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=354fca43ec5c1adaf279ef5878f7504c. It may be related to the code which you are using to get the output value...